# Dynamic Button with loop in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'm using `SwiftUI` with `Xcode-beta 4`.

I want to create dynamic button with `ForEach`. I'm using these lines of code:

```
struct Result {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: Int
}

struct ContentView : View {
    let results = [Result(score: 8), Result(score: 5), Result(score: 10)]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(results.identified(by: \.id)) { result in
                Button(action: {
                    print(result.score)
                }){
                    Text(result.score)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but `Xcode` can't compile this.

when I change `Text(result.score)` to `Text("test")` in button style, now Xcode can compile it

Comment: may be issue of type casting first cast score to string and then use in Text. like  Text("\(result.score)")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print an `Int`: `Text("\(result.score)")`

Also keep in mind that the `ForEach` syntax changed a little bit (Beta 5).
Now it should be: `results.identified(by: \.id)`

```
let results = [Result(score: 8), Result(score: 5), Result(score: 10)]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(results.identified(by: \.id)) { result in
            Button(action: {
                print(result.score)
            }){
                Text("\(result.score)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: thank you! yes it is correct. but if I change score to `String`, still I must use `double quotation` to print it

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just tested. If I change score to `String`, this works just fine: `Text(result.score)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Text("\(result.score)")

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23684524)

Comment: There wasn't any question in the original post merely a complaint that he couldn't compile when he used Text(result.score), the answer is that Text() expects to see a String and hence he should use Text("\\(result.score)").

Comment: `Try` part sounds like you are not sure and the answer itself is a bit on a short side, that's why it got to the LQP review queue, that's why I marked it as a `does not provide an answer`. If it was something like `Printing with the Text function requires a string, that can be created with the formatting construct ``Text("\(result.score)")`` `, then no one could have found a reasonable issue with this answer. But as of now it is a bit on the dubious side of the things.

Answer (score 2):

Since result.score is Int, you must convert it to String to show in Text(). Change your text button code to this one:

```
Text("\(result.score)")
```

Comment: you missed a `)` at the end of line